# crosscompile gdi-tool with mingw

Tags: c, gdi+, mingw, cross-compiling

I try to crosscompile a c-tool on linux with mingw. I use the function [GdipSaveImageToFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which i will need. This function is declared in "gdiplus.h".

My code now is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Compile-Command:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc test.c -lgdi32
```

And the error is:

```
test.c:3:21: Fehler: gdiplus.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

In english (i think):

```
test.c:3:21: Error: gdiplus.h: no such file or directory.
```

I also tried to include `<Gdiplus.h>`, `gdi.h` and much others, but no header file exists?
Has anyone an idea why? My operating system is ubuntu 11.04.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

The gdiplus headers are not in the default mingw package. The "normal" way is to use those provided by wxMax:

http://code.google.com/p/wxmax/

You'll have to fix a few case issues, though. I have built that into a debian package gdiplus-dev-mingw-i686-cross at

deb https://idefix.biozentrum.uni-wuerzburg.de/debian experimental main

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE needs to know where to find  (the <> tells it to search in predefined locations). In Visual Studio, for example, you can set those locations in the "Include Directories" options. Your IDE must have something similar

If you're using plain mingw, there must also be a way to set the locations to search for include files, check the mingw documentation

One more thing: You might already know this, but windows.h and Gdiplus.h are Windows-specific headers, you won't have them available in Ubuntu unless you do some fiddling

Answer (score 0):

"windows.h" is found, so the path should be configured correctly. I searched it on the system. The path is:

`/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include`

And there is the file `windows.h`. But if i execute there `find .|grep -i gdi` i see only one file (`wingdi.h`). And this file doesn't include the function which i need.

After this i executed `find . -type f|xargs grep -i GdipSaveImageToFile`, but unfortunaly there is no file found...

Is there a way to install this header files (and their dependencies)?

best regards

-edit-

Or alternativly does a code-file exists which can generate png-files? It this would exist i would use this file.

best regards

Comment: This is not an answer, you should add this at the end of your original question, with an "Update" title. It's the way Stack Overflow works